# Are the "viewed" fragments always recreated in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I use a viewpager with a tablayout in which I add some fragments with an adapter.
In my fragments oncreateview and onviewcreated are called.

My question is : is a fragment created again when the user scrolls to the next fragment of the tablayout and comes back to the first fragment? Or the fragments are created at the initialization of the viewpager and tablayout and then don't change?

I ask because I want to change a value from a tablayout's fragment and that change must entail a change in another fragment of the tablayout.

If my question is not clear, tell me and I will try to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `setOffscreenPageLimit` in ViewPager.

You can set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(X)
```

it means it will create `X` number of pageson either side of your current page. And once it it is out of your page range it will recreate it.

Comment: Thanks I will test it

Comment: But if it's determined for the viewpager, how can I do to set a specific offscreenlimit for each fragment of the viewpager?

Comment: I think every page of your viewpager creating a fragment instance. In that case setting your pagelimit can control fragment initialization.

Answer (score 0):

By default 1 page beside the current page is kept "in memory" and not recreated. You can change that through the following line:

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(YOUR_LIMIT);`

It is suggested that you keep this LIMIT low, you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)).

The Fragments that are within your specified limit will be kept "in memory" and will not be recreated. However Fragments that are beyond this limit will be recreated.

Comment: Thanks, so if I want all fragments recreated at each fragment scroll, I put viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);  ?

Comment: According to the implementation of this method you cant have it less than 1. So at least 1 fragment will always be "in memory".

Comment: So I can't have a fragment recreated by going to the first previous fragment?

Comment: Why do you want the fragment to be recreated in the first place? If there is some new data you want to fetch, you can do that in `onStart` or `onResume`.

Comment: In fact I have two values and a button in a fragment, I click the button and it writes the addition of the values in the next fragment of the viewpager. I want the result to change each time I click on the button to calcul.

Comment: You could find the particular `Fragment` using it's `Tag` or `Id` and make a method in that fragment, which you can call if the `Fragment` is not null